# why use Page layouts in sp 2010 when we can save a page as template and then use this new template

Tags: 2010, 2007, page-layout

I might sound idiot but why we create page layouts in sp 2010, or possible scenarios where we can use page layouts or customize them.

Answer (score 1):

You can fully customise the look and feel of a page, like when you customise a page layout in Sharepoint designer. If you create a custom page layout in Visual Studio, you can then deploy them as part of your solution (wsp) and bind them to all/specific page libraries using feature stapling or whatever your solution requires.
If you're deploying to 100 site collections, you want to be able to do this by avoiding SharePoint designer. Actually, always try and avoid SharePoint designer...

Comment: ... I ... will ... not ... rise ... to ... the ... bait ...

Answer (score 1):

You can change page layouts on the fly - so if you start with a 2-column layout and decide you would prefer to use 3-columns then you can just change it.  Tricky to do that with templates.